# How to store an iqueryable based query for delayed execution

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-sql

In my current project we have search forms to look up data from a mssql database, using Entity Framework and Linq2SQL.

The customer can define different search parameters, which result in the generation of an IQueryable, which is then used to fill up a datatable.

Now the customer would like to generate one of those search queries, but execute it in another program on a specific date, think of a birthday calendar application which sends out e-mails on the day of the birthday.

For this the query would have to be saved to the database, but as far as I've tried, retrieving the raw query from the IQueryable object, results in a non-fully generated entity framework style query.

I'm considering the following options to save the query, but I wonder which one is more future-changes-proof:

Create a mssql table which contains

1. a number of columns equals to the number of different search parameters, store the search values in each of the specific columns and regenerate the query by looking which columns are filled on
2. generate the full query first and store it fully in a text typed column
3. do both of the above, allowing easy modification and fast execution of the search query

Choosing for option 1 is ideal for allowing the customer to modify the search query, choosing for option 2 is ideal for fast execution of the query.

Which one / other method would be ideal for achieving this functionality?